# Problemas com url HTACCES - Redirecionamento 301 não funciona em uma página

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, url, redirecionamento

Fiz redirecionamentos 301 de algumas das url's do meu site recentemente e começou a dar o problema da imagem:

[image: url problemática]

Meu .htacces está assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header unset Etag
 Header unset Last-Modified 
</IfModule>

#REDIRECIONAMENTOS ***********

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MEUURLANTIGO\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.MEUURLANTIGO\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/MEUURLNOVO\.com\.br\/" [R=301,L]

#MATERIAIS

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MEUURLANTIGO\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.MEUURLANTIGO\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^material\-educativo/?$ "http\:\/\/MEUURLNOVO\.com\.br\/materiais\/" [R=301,L]

#BLOG

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MEUURLANTIGO\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.MEUURLANTIGO\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ "http\:\/\/MEUURLNOVO\.com\.br\/blog\/" [R=301,L]

#artigos

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MEUURLANTIGO\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.MEUURLANTIGO\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^blog\/impacto\-da\-internet\-nas\-empresas/?$ "http\:\/\/MEUURLNOVO\.com\.br\/blog\/impacto\-da\-internet\-nas\-empresas\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MEUURLANTIGO\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.MEUURLANTIGO\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^blog\/5\-otimos\-motivos\-para\-investir\-em\-social\-media/?$ "http\:\/\/MEUURLNOVO\.com\.br\/blog\/5\-otimos\-motivos\-para\-investir\-em\-social\-media\/" [R=301,L]
```

**obs.: o único que está funcionando é o do blog, os outros urls estão acontecendo isso**

P.S.: Me ajudem não acho o porque desse erro em lugar algum :/

Comment: Não seria pq `.htacces[s]` ta faltando um `S`? Só pra ter certeza.

Answer (score 2):

Talvez nesse formato funcione

```
Redirect 301 /blog http://meusitenovo.com.br/blog/
```

Comment: Não funciona porque meus 2 domínios estão na mesma hospedagem e apontam para a mesma pasta, se eu fizer assim ele não funciona ou dá loop infinito.